# Prometheus Target Discovery Dropped Target Labels

Tags: prometheus, service-discovery

I have Prometheus running within K8 on AWS and using service discovery to gain information regarding my infrastructure.

I have been able to use Service Discovery to retrieve target labels for metrics and nodes however I am showing 0/17 active targets pods, 0/13 node-exporter, 3/9 service endpoints 2/13 api-servers.

I have a Prometheus.yaml file within my config-map.yaml which I have placed below.

Has anyone done this before and able to shine some light on what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance

```
global:
      scrape_interval: 5s
      evaluation_interval: 5s
    rule_files:
      - /etc/prometheus/prometheus.rules
    alerting:
      alertmanagers:
      - scheme: http
        static_configs:
        - targets:
          - "alertmanager.monitoring.svc:9093"

    scrape_configs:
      - job_name: 'node-exporter'
        kubernetes_sd_configs:
          - role: endpoints
        relabel_configs:
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_endpoints_name]
          regex: 'node-exporter'
          action: keep
      
      - job_name: 'kubernetes-apiservers'

        kubernetes_sd_configs:
        - role: endpoints
        scheme: https

        tls_config:
          ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
        bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token

        relabel_configs:
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace, __meta_kubernetes_service_name, __meta_kubernetes_endpoint_port_name]
          action: keep
          regex: default;kubernetes;https

      - job_name: 'kubernetes-nodes'

        scheme: https

        tls_config:
          ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
        bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token

        kubernetes_sd_configs:
        - role: node

        relabel_configs:
        - action: labelmap
          regex: __meta_kubernetes_node_label_(.+)
        - target_label: __address__
          replacement: kubernetes.default.svc:443
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_node_name]
          regex: (.+)
          target_label: __metrics_path__
          replacement: /api/v1/nodes/${1}/proxy/metrics     
      
      - job_name: 'kubernetes-pods'

        kubernetes_sd_configs:
        - role: pod

        relabel_configs:
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape]
          action: keep
          regex: true
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_path]
          action: replace
          target_label: __metrics_path__
          regex: (.+)
        - source_labels: [__address__, __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_port]
          action: replace
          regex: ([^:]+)(?::\d+)?;(\d+)
          replacement: $1:$2
          target_label: __address__
        - action: labelmap
          regex: __meta_kubernetes_pod_label_(.+)
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
          action: replace
          target_label: kubernetes_namespace
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_name]
          action: replace
          target_label: kubernetes_pod_name
      
      - job_name: 'kube-state-metrics'
        static_configs:
          - targets: ['kube-state-metrics.kube-system.svc.cluster.local:8080']

      - job_name: 'kubernetes-cadvisor'

        scheme: https

        tls_config:
          ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
        bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token

        kubernetes_sd_configs:
        - role: node

        relabel_configs:
        - action: labelmap
          regex: __meta_kubernetes_node_label_(.+)
        - target_label: __address__
          replacement: kubernetes.default.svc:443
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_node_name]
          regex: (.+)
          target_label: __metrics_path__
          replacement: /api/v1/nodes/${1}/proxy/metrics/cadvisor
      
      - job_name: 'kubernetes-service-endpoints'

        kubernetes_sd_configs:
        - role: endpoints

        relabel_configs:
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape]
          action: keep
          regex: true
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_scheme]
          action: replace
          target_label: __scheme__
          regex: (https?)
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_path]
          action: replace
          target_label: __metrics_path__
          regex: (.+)
        - source_labels: [__address__, __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_port]
          action: replace
          target_label: __address__
          regex: ([^:]+)(?::\d+)?;(\d+)
          replacement: $1:$2
        - action: labelmap
          regex: __meta_kubernetes_service_label_(.+)
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
          action: replace
          target_label: kubernetes_namespace
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_name]
          action: replace
          target_label: kubernetes_name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the tagging config was looking for tags that didn't exist. The example I was using was from an old version of prometheus. I looked at what tags were being dropped then realised that there were Regex expressions that were not required.

Answer (score 11):

Prometheus doesn't drop labels for discovered targets on its own. It follows the provided target relabeling rules at [relabel_configs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/relabeling.html) section. So, if you see that the target contains unexpected labels or doesn't contain expected labels or the target is completely dropped, then the first thing to do is to look at `relabel_configs` section for the particular target.

Prometheus provides [/service-discovery](http://demo.robustperception.io:9090/service-discovery) page, which may help determining why the corresponding targets have the given labels. It shows two columns per each discovered target:

- Labels before target relabeling (aka `discovered labels`)
- Labels after target relabeling (aka `target labels`)

These columns help determining why a particular targets have the given labels. [This online service for debugging Prometheus relabeling rules](https://relabeler.promlabs.com/) can help understanding how Prometheus relabeling works for a particular set of discovered labels. See also [this article, which shows common patterns for Prometheus relabeling](https://valyala.medium.com/how-to-use-relabeling-in-prometheus-and-victoriametrics-8b90fc22c4b2).

Update: [vmagent](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/vmagent.html) (Prometheus-compatible scraper I work on) provides the ability to debug target-level and metric-level relabeling - see [these docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/vmagent.html#relabel-debug).

Comment: Thanks! That Relabeler debug tool is a life saver